# import a whole module at one time with Haskell

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm embarrassed with a library problem with Haskell.
I finished a library made of several files

```
src/MyLib/Firstbib.hs
src/MyLib/Secondbib.hs
...
src/MyLib/Lastbib.hs
```

At this time, After `cabal install` I can import each file separatly with

```
import MyLib.Firstbib
import MyLib.Secondbib
import MyLib.Lastbib
```

**every thing is OK**

Now, I would like to import all these part of MyLib in a simple import :

```
import MyLib
```

and I can't reach to make it.

I tried to create a file named `src/MyLib.hs` containing :

```
module MyLib where 
import MyLib.Types 
import MyLib.Functions
import MyLib.Algo.Line 
import MyLib.Algo.Point
```

and expose it with Cabal

```
Library
  -- Modules exported by the library.
  Hs-Source-Dirs:     src
  Exposed-modules:      MyLib
                      , MyLib.Functions
                      , MyLib.Types
                      , MyLib.Algo.Line
                      , MyLib.Algo.Point
```

but it doesn't work.!

What it the correct way to import many files with only one module import (as for Gtk2Hs for example)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how `MyLib` should look like -- maybe with different indentation:

```
module MyLib
  (module MyLib.Types
  ,module MyLib.Functions
  ,module MyLib.Algo.Line
  ,module MyLib.Algo.Point
  ) where 
import MyLib.Types 
import MyLib.Functions
import MyLib.Algo.Line 
import MyLib.Algo.Point
```

What happens is that when you put a module like that in your export list, you export all the symbols that *your* module knows about it.

You could potentially scope what part of this module you export, for example:

```
module ExampleLib
  (module Data.Maybe
  ) where 
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
```

The above will just re-export `fromJust` from `Data.Maybe`, not the whole `Data.Maybe` module.